# npm sqlite3 package does not work when installing on linux / invalid ELF header

Tags: node.js, linux, sqlite, npm, shopify

I am trying to get my development environment up and running for my Shopify app and it has been awhile. Shopify updates so rapidly I am forced to either reintegrate my code with a new Shopify app instance or try to get the original to work. Unfortunately, I cannot run my current application because sqlite3 will not work / install. I have tried installing from the source as recommended by the [NPM documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3). I keep getting this error:

web/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-glibc-x64/node_sqlite3.node: invalid ELF header

Apparently this has to do with the binary not matching my system, which it is supposed to after running "npm install -g sqlite3 --build-from-source". Is there a way to install a specific build so that I can simply test all the linux builds to see if I can find a potential match or see if anything works?